# Word meaning "to make valid"

Tags: single-word-requests

Usage situation:
Joan submits a document to an office.
The office validates the document; if it is not valid, they return it to her.
Joan sees the error, *makes it valid*, and resubmits it.

I'm looking for a word that means "to make valid".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"To correct" is to fix an error.

Answer (score -1):

[revalidate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/revalidate)
*tr.v.* **re·val·i·dat·ed, re·val·i·dat·ing, re·val·i·dates**
To declare valid again.

To "make it valid, and resubmit it", would be to *revalidate* it.

Comment: Per the comments against @mustafa's misleading answer, OP is looking for a word to describe what **Joan** does (correct the error). It's the **office** that revalidates (performs the validation again).